# I dropped some food into the hole under my hand brake

Tags: nissan, handbrake

2014 Nissan Versa

I dropped a nut (**like a peanut, walnut**) into the small hole under my hand brake. The nut is about 2/3 the size of the hole. There seems to be no way for me to get it out.

[image]

- Does this matter?
- Do I need to get it out or I can just leave it?

Comment: Not really an answer, but finding food stuff that's been in a car for a long time is pretty gross. Especially if it's moldy. I was looking for the spare tire to a car once and a cloud of flies appeared before me as I opened the trunk to check.

Comment: If it's a food nut, why is the picture showing a fastener nut?

Comment: That bolt looks like it's fixed in place.  @tlhIngan

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it probably doesn't matter.  If you can get it out with a magnet or wire or a stick with tape on the end, by all means try.  However, it appears that this hole is only used for adjusting your emergency brake; hence, you cause no issues by having an extra nut down the hole.

As a general rule of thumb: **If nothing's moving down there, nothing can jam it.**

Comment: I don't think walnuts or peanuts are a ferrous material though   :-)

Answer (score 2):

Couple of tools to use for situations like this.  Magnetic probe which is a rod on the end of which is a magnet.  Just make sure to hold onto it tightly or use a lanyard.

Another is called a claw tool.  Small stick with a plunger on one side and claws on the other.  Poke into recess, press plunger and the claws open.  Get it over the target and let go of plunger and claws close and grab it.  Pull tool out carefully.

Third is a hemostat - small pliers-like surgical tool.  They make a long one and call it a fish hook remover.

Fourth - putty or chewing gum on the end of a stick.  Just be careful not to make it worse.

Fifth - vacuum with nozzle necked down.  Stick a straw in the end and duct tape it to force all the air to go through the straw.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove the entire central console. Look for little screws near the edges, and you may need to remove other trim panels further forward. Car makers love to have panels snapping into other panels to hide the last screw.

Answer (score 1):

I dropped a piece of food into the handbrake area of my 2012 Nissan Sentra. I was able to get it out with 2 (10") wooden skewers, stabbing the food with one and stabilizing it with the other as I drew it out. Hope someone finds that technique helpful.